# Finding sold out product pages from URL in bulk using importXML

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I have to find out from tens of thousands of URLs which products are sold out. My idea was to put the URLs in a spreadsheet and get a value with importXML when it says 'sold out'. Example URL: https://www.conrad.com/p/logitech-usb-headset-h330-909899

'sold out' shown on example page

[image]

My attempt:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//*[@id='ccpjr']/body/main/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/span")
```

('A1' contains a URL like `'https://www.conrad.com/p/logitech-usb-headset-h330-909899'`)

I was hoping it would show: 'Sold out' in the cell, instead it says: `Error: Imported content is empty"`

I appreciate any help, but I must warn that my knowledge in this area is unfortunately limited. So I would appreciate it even more if there is a solution that is easily applicable for me.

Answer (score 0):

The "Sold Out" is determined after loading. After loading, the site determines the stock quantity by calling this API url: `https://www.conrad.com/restservices/COM/products/pricesAndAvailabilities?net=false&id=909899`

The data returned is JSON, so you cannot use `ImportXML`. Instead, add [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/master/ImportJSON.gs) to your sheet (Tools > Script Editor).

Then use this formula to get the stock number. (It just shows the number for stock quantity, not "Sold Out")

```
=ImportJSON("https://www.conrad.com/restservices/COM/products/pricesAndAvailabilities?net=false&id=909899","/body/availability/stockQuantity","noHeaders")
```

Note that the same item id is at the end of the original URL and also the API url, so you can use that to make the URLs you need.